# Cannot seem to expand /dev/mapper/centos-root LV in CentOS 7 virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, storage, centos-7

I keep running out of space in `/dev/mapper/centos-root` As a temporary fix I delete the files/directories I'm working with, but this is hindering my productivity. I should have made the CentOS VM larger than 20 GBs to begin with, but it's too late for that now. I shutdown the VM and added 20GBs to the VMDK (vDisk), but I can't seem to get the OS to use it where I need it, which is in the **/dev/mapper/centos-root logical volume**

Here is the output of `lsblk`:

```
    root@CentOS-7:/# lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   30G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0   29G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0   17G  0 lvm  /
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0              11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Output of `pgs` `vgs` and `lvs` commands:

```
    root@CentOS-7:/# pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  centos lvm2 a--  <19.00g    0
root@CentOS-7:/# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  centos   1   2   0 wz--n- <19.00g    0
root@CentOS-7:/# lvs
  LV   VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root centos -wi-ao---- <17.00g
  swap centos -wi-ao----   2.00g
```

As you can see, I have 10 GBs of unallocated space. I need to apply it to the logical volume, but everything I have tried so far has failed. I think I do not have available extent to use, but am not sure. I have plenty of space on the host machine where the VM is stored, I just need to know how to actually get the OS to use it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. The **swap partition** was in the way. [Once I removed it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTPO4O4rGvI&t=5s) I was able to expand out `/dev/mapper/centos-root` like so:

```
#Delete & Create new volume
root@CentOS-7:/# fdisk /dev/sda
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1,2, default 2):
Partition 2 is deleted

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 96.6 GB, 96636764160 bytes, 188743680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000b14c7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200   125829119    61864960   8e  Linux LVM

Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (2 primary, 0 extended, 2 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p):
Using default response p
Partition number (3,4, default 3):
First sector (125829120-188743679, default 125829120):
Using default value 125829120
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (125829120-188743679, default 188743679):
Using default value 188743679
Partition 3 of type Linux and of size 30 GiB is set

Command (m for help): t
Partition number (1-3, default 3):
Hex code (type L to list all codes): 8e
Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'Linux LVM'

Command (m for help): wq
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
```

I then ran...

```
pvresize /dev/sda2
lvextend /dev/mapper/centos-root -l +100%FREE
xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/centos-root
```